# Make numbers 1 - 30 using the digits 2, 0, 2, 4

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, formation-of-numbers, number-property

Try to make all numbers 1-30 using the digits 2, 0, 2, 4.

Rules:

Use all four digits exactly once.

Allowed operations: $+, -, \times, ÷, !$ (factorial), x^y (exponentiation), √ (square root).

Parentheses and concatenation are allowed. (e.g. 20+(2∗4)).

Squaring uses the digit 2.

Keep the order "2, 0, 2, 4" in all expressions.

The modulus operator is not allowed.

Rounding is not allowed.

Comment: Some cosmetic corrections should be applied, as there are 2 twos and no nine, so keep the order "2 0 2 4".

Comment: Is the `−` operator supposed to include both subtraction and and arithmetic negation?

Answer (score 17):

Complete solution that doesn't use concatenation.

> $1 = 2 + 0! + 2 - 4 \\ 2 = 2 \times 0 - 2 + 4 \\ 3 = 2^0 -2 + 4 \\ 4 = 2 + 0 - 2 + 4 \\ 5 = -2^0 + 2 + 4 \\ 6 = 2 \times 0 + 2 + 4 \\ 7 = 2^0 + 2 + 4 \\ 8 = 2+0+2+4 \\ 9 = 2^0 + 2 \times 4 \\ 10 = 2 + 0 + 2\times 4 \\ 11 = 2 + 0! + 2 \times 4 \\ 12 = 2^{0!+2} + 4 \\ 13 = -2 - 0! + 2^4 \\ 14 = -2 + 0 + 2^4 \\ 15 = -2^0 + 2^4 \\ 16 = 2 \times 0 + 2^4 \\ 17 = 2^0 + 2^4 \\ 18 = 2+0 + 2^4 \\ 19 = 2 + 0! + 2^4 \\ 20 = -2 + 0 - 2 + 4! \\ 21 = -2^0 - 2 + 4! \\ 22 = 2 \times 0 - 2 + 4!  \\ 23 = 2^0 - 2 + 4! \\ 24 = 2 + 0 - 2+ 4! \\ 25 = 2 + 0! - 2 + 4! \\ 26 = 2 \times 0 + 2 + 4! \\ 27 = 2^0 + 2 + 4!  \\ 28 = 2 + 0 + 2  + 4! \\ 29 = 2 + 0! + 2 +4! \\ 30 = (2 + 0!) \times 2 + 4!$

Comment: You can avoid leading minus with 5: (2+0)/2 + 4 and 20: (2+0!+2)*4.

Comment: @ZizyArcher Thanks. Actually, I was trying to avoid brackets ...

Answer (score 9):

I'm making this a community wiki so the answers aren't split among multiple…answers.

1

> $$1=2^{0^{2^4}}$$

2

> $$2=\frac{2^0}{2}\cdot4=-2^0\cdot2+4$$

3

> $$3=2^0-2+4=-(2+0)/2+4$$

4

> $$4=2+0-2+4=2+0\cdot 2+\sqrt{4}$$

5

> $$5=\frac{(2+0)}{2}+4=-2^0+2+4=2^{0^2}+4$$

6

> $$6=2\cdot0+2+4$$

7

> $$7=2^0+2+4$$

8

> $$8=2+0+2+4=2^{0+2}+4$$

9

> $$9=2^0+2\cdot4$$

10

> $$10=2+0+2\cdot4$$

11

> $$11=2+0!+2\cdot4$$

12

> $$12 = (2+0) \times (2+4)$$

13

> $$13=(2+0!)^2+4=-2-0!+2^4$$

14

> $$14=2(0!+2+4)$$

15

> $$15=-2^0 + 2^4$$

16

> $$16=2^{0+2}\cdot4$$

17

> $$17=2^0+2^4$$

18

> $$18=2+0+2^4$$

19

> $$19=2+0!+2^4$$

20

> $$20=(2+0!+2)\cdot4=-2-0-2+4!$$

21

> $$21=-2^0-2+4!$$

22

> $$22=2\times0-2+4!$$

23

> $$23=2^0-2+4!$$

24

> $$24=2+0-2+4!$$

25

> $$25=\frac{2+0}2+4!$$

26

> $$26=20+2+4$$

27

> $$27=2-0!+2+4!$$

28

> $$28=2+0+2+4!$$

29

> $$29=2+0!+2+4!$$

30

> $$30=(2^0+2)!+4!$$

Bonus solutions!

> $$31=$$
>  $$32=(2+0)\cdot2^4$$
>  $$33=(2+0!)^2+4!$$
>  $$34=\frac{20}2+4!$$

Comment: The bonus 31 and 33 solutions don't work because the digits aren't in order

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure who wrote those, though.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks, this was fun! Here's what I came up with:

> $$1 = {(2 + 0 + 2) \over 4}$$
>  $$2 = {2 \times 0 - 2 + 4}$$
>  $$3 = {-(2 + 0) \over 2} + 4$$
>  $$4 = 2 + 0 - 2 + 4$$
>  $$5 = {(2 + 0) \over 2} + 4$$
>  $$6 = 2 \times 0 + 2 + 4$$
>  $$7 = 2^0 + 2 + 4$$
>  $$8 = 2 + 0 + 2 + 4$$
>  $$9 = 2^0 + 2 \times 4$$
>  $$10 = 20 \times 2 / 4$$
>  $$11 = (20 + 2) / \sqrt{4}$$
>  $$12 = (2^0 + 2) \times 4$$
>  Skipped this and came back to it after 19 where I finally realized $0! = 1$:
>  $$13 = -2 - 0! + 2^4$$
>  $$14 = -2 + 0 + 2^4$$
>  $$15 = -2^0 + 2^4$$
>  $$16 = 2 \times 0 + 2^4$$
>  $$17 = 2^0 + 2^4$$
>  $$18 = 2 + 0 + 2^4$$
>  $$19 = 2 + 0! + 2^4$$
>  $$20 = 20 + 2 - \sqrt{4}$$
>  $$21 = -2^0 - 2 + 4!$$
>  $$22 = -2 + 0 + 24$$
>  $$23 = -2^0 + 24$$
>  $$24 = 2 \times 0 + 24$$
>  $$25 = 2^0 + 24$$
>  $$26 = 2 + 0 + 24$$
>  $$27 = 2 + 0! + 24$$
>  $$28 = 2 + 0 + 2 + 4!$$
>  $$29 = 2 + 0! + 2 + 4!$$
>  $$30 = (2 + 0!) \times 2 + 4!$$

I was struggling for a while at 13 and 19 before I made that discovery I mentioned, that was huge, and made the rest of the numbers a lot easier to figure out.

Comment: I think you meant 2 instead of the first 4 for 1.

Comment: Thanks, Pierre, you're correct. I was copying from a piece of paper where I'd worked it all out and didn't double-check.

Answer (score 5):

The answer:

> 1. (2+0+2)÷4
>  2. 2+(0×2×4)
>  3. (2+0)÷2+$\sqrt{4}$
>  4. 2×0×2+4
>  5. (2+0)÷2+4
>  6. ($\sqrt{2}$+0)×$\sqrt{2}$+4
>  7. $2^0$+2+4
>  8. 2+0+2+4
>  9. 2+0!+2+4
>  10. 2+0+2×4
>  11. 2+$0!$+2×4
>  12. (2+0)(2+4)
>  13. -2-0!+$2^4$
>  14. -2+0+$2^4$
>  15. -2+0!+$2^4$
>  16. (2×0)+$2^4$
>  17. (2×0)!+$2^4$
>  18. 2+0+$2^4$
>  19. 2!+0!+$2^4$
>  20. -2 + 0 -2 + 4!
>  21. -2-(0×2)!+4!
>  22. -2+0×2+4!
>  23. -2+(0×2)!+4!
>  24. (2×0×2)+4!
>  25. (2×0×2)!+4!
>  26. 2+0+2+4!
>  27. 2+(0×2)!+4!
>  28. 2+0!×2+4!
>  29. 2+0!+2+4!
>  30. (2+0!)×2+4!

Comment: Oh, nice! I love how you got the square root of 2 in there! +1 for that alone

Comment: How do you get $((2+0)*\sqrt{2}))^4 = 20$ ?

Comment: @FlorianF My guess is a mistake trying to use $2^4 + \sqrt{2}^4 = 20$

Comment: Yes, ((2+0)*$\sqrt{2}$))$^4$ = 20 is indeed a miscalculation, which I overlooked, while trying to accomplish $2^4$ + $\sqrt(2)^4$ = 20. Thanks for pointing that out. I've changed the 20th number for simpler -2 + 0 -2 + 4!.

Answer (score 2):

Great puzzle, thanks for posting!

> $1 = 2^0+2-\sqrt{4}$ 
>  $2 = 2+0+2-\sqrt{4}$ 
>  $3=2^0-2+4$ 
>  $4=2+0-2+4$ 
>  $5=2^0+2+\sqrt{4}$ 
>  $6=(2\times0)+2+4$ 
>  $7=2^0+2+4$ 
>  $8=2+0+2+4$ 
>  $9=2^0+2\times4$ 
>  $10=2+0+2\times4$ 
>  $11=2+0!+(2\times4)$ 
>  $12=(2^0/2)\times4!$ 
>  $13=-2-0!+(2^4)$ 
>  $14=20-2-4$ 
>  $15=-(2^0)+2^4$ 
>  $16=(2\times0)+2^4$ 
>  $17=2^0+2^4$ 
>  $18=20+2-4$ 
>  $19=2+0!+(2^4)$ 
>  $20=20+2-\sqrt{4}$ 
>  $21=-(2^0)-2+4!$ 
>  $22=20-2+4$ 
>  $23=(2^0)-2+4!$ 
>  $24=20+2+\sqrt{4}$ 
>  $25=2^0+24$ 
>  $26=20+2+4$ 
>  $27=2^0+2+4!$ 
>  $28=2+0+2+4!$ 
>  $29=2+0!+2+4!$ 
>  $30=(2^0+2)!+4!$

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

> 1: $(2+0+2)/4=4/4=1$
> 2: $2+(0\times2)/4=2+0=2$
> 3: $2^0-2+4=1-2+4=-1+4=3$
> 4: $2-0-2+4=0+4=4$
> 5: $2^{0\times2}+4=1+4=5$
> 6: $2+(0\times2)+4=2+4=6$
> 7: $2^0+2+4=1+2+4=7$
> 8: $2+0+2+4=4+4=8$
> 9: I'll figure something out
> 10: $(2^0+2)!+4=3!+4=6+4=10$
> 11: I'll figure something out
> 12: $(2+0)(2+4)=2(6)=12$