# Make numbers 1 - 30 using the digits 2, 0, 2, 5

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, formation-of-numbers, number-property

Try to make all numbers 1-30 using the digits 2, 0, 2, 5.

Rules:

Use all four digits exactly once.

Allowed operations: $+,−,×,÷,!
 \text{ (factorial)}, !! \text{ (double factorial)}, !!! \text{ (triple factorial)} ,  x^y \text{ (exponentiation)}, \sqrt{x} \text{ (square root).}$

Parentheses and concatenation are allowed. (e.g. 20+(2∗5)).

Squaring uses the digit 2.

Keep the order "2, 0, 2, 5" in all expressions.

The modulus operator is not allowed.

Rounding is not allowed.

**Follow up:** Can you continue till 100?

Inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124968/make-numbers-1-30-using-the-digits-2-0-2-4)

Comment: I don't find these "Make numbers 1..30" questions interesting.  Most of the expressions are too easy and there are to many answers.  A better way would be to search for one specially difficult number to form and ask to find how it can be made.

Comment: Also, you're a year early.

Comment: @Bass I was wondering about how you would get the answer with 2 0 2 5. Is that bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used $\sqrt{\ }$, nor any double/triple factorial.

> $1 = -2+0-2+5\\2 = 2+0*2*5\\3 = -2+0*2+5\\4 = 2-0!-2+5\\5 = 2+0-2+5\\6 = 2+0!-2+5\\7 = 2*0+2+5\\8 = -2+0+2*5\\9 = 2+0+2+5\\10= 2*0+2*5\\11= 2^0+2*5\\12= 2+0+2*5\\13= 20-2-5\\14= 2*(0+2+5)\\15= (2-0!+2)*5\\16= 2*(0!+2+5)\\17= 20+2-5\\18= 2*(-0!+2*5)\\19= (2+0+2)!-5\\20= (2+0+2)*5\\21= (2+0!)*(2+5)\\22= 2*(0!+2*5)\\23= 20-2+5\\24= (2-0!-2+5)!\\25= (2+0!+2)*5\\26= 2^0+25\\27= 20+2+5\\28= 2+0!+25\\29= (2+0+2)!+5\\30= 2*(0!+2)*5$
>  Thanks to Bass for getting rid of the use of double factorial in 26 and 28.

Comment: Nice. Try the follow up. I think you can do it.

Comment: How about "2^0+25" and "2+0!+25" instead of the clunky double factorials?

Comment: @Bass Oh, of course. I keep forgetting concatenation.