# Getting The Numbers 33 Through 99 Only Using 2, 0, 2, and 4

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, number-property

How do you get the numbers 33-99 by using the numbers 2,0,2,4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make numbers 1 - 30 using the digits 2, 0, 2, 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/124968/make-numbers-1-30-using-the-digits-2-0-2-4)

Comment: There are already quite a few questions almost exactly like this—while the range is different, it's fundamentally the same thing being asked.

Comment: These kind of puzzles **require a list of allowed operations**. Exactly what are we allowed to do? Addition? Division? Exponentiation? Concatenation? Square roots? N-th roots? Floor? Ceiling? Factorial? Trigonometry? Parentheses? And so forth.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming we can use exponentiation, factorial, and N-th root operations 
Here are my solutions so far --> 
(Sorry for the bad formatting!)

> 33 = (2 + 0!)<sup>2</sup> + 4! 
>  34 = 2 $\times$ (0! + 4<sup>2</sup>) 
>  35 = $\dfrac{4 + 2 + 0!}{.2}$ 
>  36 = (2 + 0!)! $\times$ (2 + 4) 
>  37 = (4 + 2)<sup>2</sup> + 0! 
>  38 = ? 
>  39 = $\left(\dfrac{4}{.2} \times 2 \right) - 0!$ 
>  40 = $\left(\dfrac{4}{.2} \times 2 \right) + 0$ 
>  41 = $\left(\dfrac{4}{.2} \times 2 \right) + 0!$ 
>  42 = 2 $\times$ (4! - (2 + 0!)) 
>  43 = 2 $\times$ (4! - 2) - 0! 
>  44 = (2 $\times$ 4!) - (0 $\times$ 2) 
>  45 = $\dfrac{(4 \times 2) + 0!}{.2}$ 
>  46 = (4! - (0 $\times$ 2)!) $\times$ 2 
>  47 = ? 
>  48 = 4<sup>2</sup> $\times$ (2 + 0!) 
>  49 = (2 + 4 + 0!)<sup>2</sup> 
>  50 = (4 + 0!)<sup>2</sup> $\times$ 2 
>  51 = ? 
>  52 = (4! + 2) $\times$ (2 + 0) 
>  53 = ((4! + 2) $\times$ 2) + 0! 
>  54 = ? 
>  55 = ? 
>  56 = ? 
>  57 = ? 
>  58 = ? 
>  59 = $\dfrac{4!}{2 \times .2} - 0!$ 
>  60 = $\dfrac{2 + 4}{.2} \times 2$ 
>  61 = $\dfrac{4!}{2 \times .2} + 0!$ 
>  62 = 4<sup>2 + 0!</sup> - 2 
>  63 = 2<sup>2 + 4</sup> - 0! 
>  64 = 2<sup>2 + 4</sup> + 0 
>  65 = 2<sup>2 + 4</sup> + 0! 
>  66 = (4! - 2) $\times$ (2 + 0!) 
>  67 = ? 
>  68 = ? 
>  69 = ? 
>  70 = ? 
>  71 = ? 
>  72 = ? 
>  73 = ? 
>  74 = ? 
>  75 = $\dfrac{4^2 - 0!}{.2}$ 
>  76 = ? 
>  77 = ? 
>  78 = ? 
>  79 = $\dfrac{4^2}{.2} - 0!$ 
>  80 = $\dfrac{4^2}{.2} + 0$ 
>  81 = $\dfrac{4^2}{.2} + 0!$ 
>  82 = ? 
>  83 = (2 + 0!)<sup>4</sup> + 2 
>  84 = ? 
>  85 = $\dfrac{4^2 + 0!}{.2}$ 
>  86 = ? 
>  87 = ? 
>  88 = ? 
>  89 = ? 
>  90 = ? 
>  91 = ? 
>  92 = (4! - 0!) $\times$ 2 $\times$ 2 
>  93 = ? 
>  94 = ? 
>  95 = $\dfrac{\dfrac{4}{.2} - 0!}{.2}$ 
>  96 = ? 
>  97 = ? 
>  98 = ? 
>  99 = $\dfrac{4}{.2 \times .2} - 0!$

I haven't figured out the answer for the numbers with the question marks yet. 
I'll try to update as soon as I get the answers